# Using one wildcard from input with multiple wildcards to create output file in Snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to write a rule that runs a function in shell for a list of input files that contains multiple wildcards but only output one file using one wildcard from the inputs:

```
    rule A:
       input:
           lambda wildcards: glob(fileDir + '/Outputs/{run}_*.fastq.gz'.format(run=wildcards.run_id)
       output:
           fileDir+"/Outputs/{run}.txt"
       shell:
          """
          myfunction {input} > {output}
          """
```

Where my target `rule all` and top of my Snakefile looks like:

```
run_id=utilities.getrunid(sample_sheet)

    rule all:
        input:
            text_file=fileDir+"/Outputs/{run}.txt"
```

Though I keep getting an error indicating that `Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files: {run}`.

The input contains multiple wildcards which I expand on and generate in a rule earlier, but I really only want to use the `run_id` wildcard to generate the output for my last rule:

```
    samples=expand(fileDir + "/Outputs/{run}_{sample_name}_R{read}_001.fastq.gz", 
run=run_id, sample_name=samples, read=[1,2])
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

input files should be specified explicitly if you don't have output field in a rule.

```
run_id=utilities.getrunid(sample_sheet)

rule all:
    input:
        text_file=expand(fileDir+"{run}_{sample_name}_R{read}_001.txt", run=run_id, sample_name=samples, read=[1,2])
```